# Python 3.0 `wsgiref` server not functioning

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsgi, wsgiref

I can't seem to get the `wsgiref` module to work at all under Python 3.0. It works fine under 2.5 for me, however. Even when I try the [example in the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/wsgiref.html?highlight=wsgiref#examples), it fails. It fails so hard that even if I have a print function above where I do: "`from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server`", it never gets printed for some reason. It doesn't thow any errors when run, and it just displays a blank page in the browser and doesn't log any sort of request.

Does anybody know what the problem may be? Thanks!

Comment: there's no print statement in python3.0, do you mean function?

Comment: @SilentGhost, yes I do mean function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[issue 4718:wsgiref package totally broken](http://bugs.python.org/issue4718). sorry about that.

Comment: Wow that is incredibly lame that they released Python 3.0 with a COMPLETELY broken package. Hell, they should have at least removed it until they could fix it.

Comment: There's no point in removing a package to put in back in a x.x.1 release. Just wait until 2009-2-13.

Answer (score 0):

You're in uncharted territory with WSGI on Python 3.0 I'm afraid.

WEB-SIG knew long ago that wsgiref was broken going into 3.0, but chose to do nothing about it. The spec hasn't been updated to cope with 3.0; pushing WSGI forwards even for the things everyone pretty-much agrees on is just agonisingly slow. It's depressing and senseless.

So yeah, it's easy to fix the obvious error with header unpacking in simple_server, but you'll still be running on a server that has been converted from Python 2-to-3 automatically and not really tested, with no de-jure standard to say exactly what it should do... never mind framework compatibility.

Python 3.0 for web scripting: needs some work.